# Redis vs elastic search in my use case

Tags: c#, architecture, software-design

I am about to create a project that monitors our cache usage.
What I mean ?
After each cache operation (Add/Get/Remove), I will save data e.g Class name, size of object (or byte[]), duration operation took and other fields that i may need.
Then i want to enable querying, or use a tool like kibana to visualize the data, to show in graphs how many instances i put of each class type, what is the average Add/Get time, if some instances of same class took longer to add to cache - I want to know and maybe investigate these objects.

I am wondering if i should use Elasticsearch to store the data or maybe redis/mongoDB. And what about visualize tools.
**What should be considered**

1. IO - read/write should be fast
2. Deployment - fast and comfortable

Answer (score 0):

You should use loki.js, which is incredibly fast & supports field indexing for faster document access and performs really well (near 500,000 ops/second on an average dev machine).

This is something much faster then redis, elasticsearch. I have used all three but found this one something much faster then others.